# JDBC template giving error for Query using "like"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbctemplate

I am not getting how to use %?% in the query below. It's giving me error:

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select
>   * from names where name like '%?%']

Problem:

```
String sql = "select * from names where name like ?";
List<NamesModel> names = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{searchName}, new NamesRowMapper());
```

Comment: Always add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Also, please show input.

Comment: I'm passing string value as input. for Eg:  
String username = "XYZ";
List<Names> names = namesDao.getAllmatchingNames(username);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception tells you that you can't bind into quoted value. Below won't work:

```
String sql = "select * from names where name like '%?%'";
List<NamesModel> names = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 
        new Object[]{ searchName }, new NamesRowMapper());
```

The correct way is to add `%` around `searchName` parameter value:

```
String sql = "select * from names where name like ?";
List<NamesModel> names = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 
        new Object[]{ "%" + searchName + "%"}, new NamesRowMapper());
```